# Javascript combinator from option values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an eCommerce web app that asks the user, "who is responsible for each shipping obligation, the *Buyer* or the *Seller?*"

My HTML uses dropdown option values for each question:

```
  <label for="firstCarrier">Whose obligation is First Carrier?</label>
  <select id="incoterms">
    <option value="Buyer">Buyer</option>
    <option value="Seller">Seller</option>
  </select>

      <label for="alongShip">Whose obligation is Alongside Ship?</label>
  <select id="incoterms">
    <option value="Buyer">Buyer</option>
    <option value="Seller">Seller</option>
  </select>
```

(And so on for each obligation...)

After selecting Buyer or Seller for each obligation, the user clicks Submit and the program returns the correct "INCO Term" (EXW, FCA, etc.):

```
import combinate from "combinate";

const values = {
  party: ['buyer', 'seller'],
  obligation: ['firstCarrier', 'alongsideShip', 'onBoard', 'arrival', 'destinationPlace'],
  incoterm: ['EXW', 'FCA', 'FAS', 'FOB', 'CFR', 'CIF', 'CPT', 'CIP', 'DPU', 'DAP', 'DDP'],
};

const combinations = combinate(options);

console.log(options);

// Get all relevant combinations
// Omit irrelevant combinations
```

**How do I combine the user's answers to produce the correct INCO term after clicking Submit?**

[image: INCO Terms Chart]

Answer (score 0):

"Combinate" create an object with **ALL** possible combinations, which is not your case as I understand.

Your term is determined by the party responsible for the last step. For example, if the Seller is responsible for Arrival, he must be responsbile for Onboard. I would do it directly in the option as following:

```
  <label>Please select the obligations of BUYER</label>
  <select id="incoterms">
    <option value="DDP">Buyer Warehouse</option>
    <option value="DAP">Buyer Warehouse + Destination Place</option>
    <option value="DPU">Buyer Warehouse + Destination Place + Alongside Ship</option>
    ... ...
  </select>
```

and by this way, you get directly the Term. But you have to think about how to display the long option text.

Comment: I'm going to use checkboxes to save space for the text.

Comment: A good idea and it's easier for users to access.